# correct way to finish application

Tags: android, exit

I use following code to stop my app:

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

However after I finish my app I can see in the application manager my app still has `stop` button enabled.Does this mean the app is still running?Moreover the android studio thinks app is running too.
If I finish the app with this code:

```
   this.finish();
   System.exit(0);
```

Android studio treats app as finished, but app manager still shows stop button enabled.
I read calling System.exit is unpreferable way of finishing the app.
What is the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

**In short, don't worry about it.**

You should run checks to ensure you aren't [leaking a Context](https://github.com/square/leakcanary), but in general you don't need to worry about your App staying "active".

This simply means that it hasn't been fully terminated yet, because Android hasn't needed to do so. Until then, it keeps it partially alive to be able to bring it back quickly if the user wants it again.

This doesn't take any additional processing resources to keep it alive. Only some memory. When Android deems it necessary to claim resources, it will kill your App fully.

Just keep using `finish();`.

The Android Lifecycle:

[image: Android Lifecycle]

Comment: Thanks!Will android start my app from scratch in case if it decided to bring it back?I mean should I release all resources before finish()?

Comment: It will start your App almost from scratch. I will post an image to the lifecycle in the answer. You can use `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` in order to get back to your previous state: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your app to be shown in the overview screen when it finishes, simply add the `android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"` to your `activity` tag in the manifest. No need to use `System.exit(0)`.

Comment: The problem is not it in the list of recent apps.The problem is application manager(in the android settings) and android studio think the app is still running

Answer (score 0):

no need to use this.finish();
just finish(); is ok
app manager always show the app is running because killing a app may occur misbehavior to its activitys.

```
public void EXIT(View view) 
{
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Quit Application on Button click use this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startActivity(intent);
```

Try it..

To kill the complete app and remove it from Runningapp list kill the app through its pid(its nasty)... use this lines before above code.

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```